# How to get an AdminClient Websphere object without using a username or password ?

Tags: java, websphere

I use the following code and it works:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_HOST, "localhost");
props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_PORT, port); //2809
props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE, AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE_RMI);
props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_SECURITY_ENABLED, "true");
props.setProperty(AdminClient.USERNAME, user);
props.setProperty(AdminClient.PASSWORD, password);
adminClient = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(props);
```

but I'd like to find a way to not use a user name or password, does anyone have any idea how to achieve this? Maybe a J2C authentication alias of WAS could be used here?

Comment: You can use J2C authentication alias if this code is run from within WAS. Though, it is probably not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use J2C authentication alias, check the following snippet

```
import com.ibm.wsspi.security.auth.callback.Constants;
import com.ibm.wsspi.security.auth.callback.WSMappingCallbackHandlerFactory;
import javax.resource.spi.security.PasswordCredential;
import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
...
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put(Constants.MAPPING_ALIAS, YOUR_J2C_AUTHENTICATION_ALIAS);
CallbackHandler callbackHandler = null;
try {
    callbackHandler = WSMappingCallbackHandlerFactory.getInstance().getCallbackHandler(map, null);
} catch (NotImplementedException e) {
    logger.error(e);
    return;
}
LoginContext loginContext;
try {
    loginContext = new LoginContext("DefaultPrincipalMapping", callbackHandler);
} catch (LoginException e) {
logger.error(e);
return;
}
try {
    loginContext.login();
} catch (LoginException e) {
    logger.error(e);
    return;
}
Subject subject = loginContext.getSubject();
Set credentials = subject.getPrivateCredentials();
PasswordCredential passwordCredential = (PasswordCredential) credentials.iterator().next();
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_HOST, "localhost");
props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_PORT, port); //2809
props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE, AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE_RMI);
props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_SECURITY_ENABLED, "true");
props.setProperty(AdminClient.USERNAME, passwordCredential.getUserName());
props.setProperty(AdminClient.PASSWORD, new String(passwordCredential.getPassword()));
adminClient = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(props);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative you have (as far as I am aware) would be to configure your soap.client.props with the username/password and run the wsadmin script without connection/authentication information.  In that scenario, you can leverage WebSphere's ability to protect the password within the properties file.  There are two caveats to that scenario though.

1. If you utilize the soap.client.props in the WebSphere profile, anyone running wsadmin would be leveraging that username/password.  This could be a security issue.  Though you can work around this by using the 'wsadmin.sh -p' option and specifying a special props file at execution time.
2. WebSphere sucks at protecting the password out of the box.  It only applies an XOR, which can be easily reversed.  Unless you've written your own custom encryption for WebSphere.

Answer (score 0):

`AdminClient` uses the current run-as subject (as determined by the static `getRunAsSubject`/`setRunAsSubject` methods in `WSSubject`). If you provide a user and password during the creation of the `AdminClient`, then WebSphere actually performs a login and changes the run-as subject on the current thread.

I would expect (to be tested) that if there is already a run-as user and you don't provide a user/password when creating the `AdminClient`, then WebSphere uses the current run-as subject. If that is correct, then it should be enough to use the `@RunAs` annotation on the servlet or EJB and map the corresponding role to the user you want in the admin console.